# Issue on including dependencies in jRuby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I'm trying to packaging up a jRuby gem using internal dependencies. So for example I included 'fastercsv' gem into *vendor/jruby/1.9/gems/fastercsv-1.5.4* and I used the ':path' argument in my Gemfile, see below:

```
gem 'fastercsv', '~> 1.5.4',
 :path => "vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/fastercsv-1.5.4"
```

Now the issue is that I'm getting

```
Could not find gem 'fastercsv (~> 0.9.2.2) java' in source at vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/fastercsv-0.9.2.2.
```

Any idea on how I can fix that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the gem unpacked there? does `vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/fastercsv-1.5.4/fastercsv.gemspec` exist?

Comment: no .gemspec is not there, I put fastercsv gem in the vendor folder with jruby -s bundle install

Comment: Ok. `gem x, path: y` expects the gem to be unpacked at that location -- ie. the gemspec and source exist at that path.

Comment: Uhm..I tried doing gem unpack fastercsv but it gives me the same result as "bundle install" and same error as above